# Не работает скрипт end нажатия на кнопку при нажатии кнопки markup

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток,

Всё работает за исключением последней кнопки которая должна по нажатию на неё выводить сообщение но при нажатии вылетает ошибка:

```
Windows PowerShell

Попробуйте новую кроссплатформенную оболочку PowerShell (https://aka.ms/pscore6)

(venv) PS C:\Users\d.chapaev\Desktop\TGBot> python main.py
2022-08-12 16:24:38,075 (__init__.py:878 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
2022-08-12 16:24:38,080 (__init__.py:880 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\PycharmProjects\TGBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 874, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\PycharmProjects\TGBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 946, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\PycharmProjects\TGBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1021, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\PycharmProjects\TGBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 977, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\PycharmProjects\TGBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 154, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\PycharmProjects\TGBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 98, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\Desktop\TGBot\main.py", line 48, in search
    val1 = db_table_val(message.text)
  File "C:\Users\d.chapaev\Desktop\TGBot\main.py", line 22, in db_table_val
    return film.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**Вот сам код:**

```
    import telebot
from telebot import types
from pathlib import Path
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')
ph = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
db_fn = Path("C:/Users/d.chapaev/Desktop/TGBot/db.db")

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_fn, check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Error", error)
if not (db_fn.exists() and db_fn.stat().st_size > 0):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"file [{db_fn.resolve()}] is empty or doesn't exist!")


def db_table_val(number: int):
    film = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM list WHERE id=?", (number,))
    conn.commit()
    return film.fetchone()[0]


def db_table_pic(picnumber: int):
    pics = cursor.execute("SELECT pic FROM list WHERE id=?", (picnumber,))
    conn.commit()
    return pics.fetchone()[0]


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
        kb1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        kb1.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='НАЗВАНИЯ ФИЛЬМОВ', callback_data='button'))
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=ph, caption='ВСЕ БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ ФИЛЬМЫ                                                   ЖМИ НА КНОПКУ  «УЗНАТЬ НАЗВАНИЯ ФИЛЬМОВ»', reply_markup=kb1)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'button':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'ДЛЯ ПРОСМОТРА ФИЛЬМА ВВЕДИТЕ КОД В ФОРМАТЕ<<123>>')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def search(message):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Искать фильмы")
        val1 = db_table_val(message.text)
        pic1 = db_table_pic(message.text)
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=pic1, caption=val1, reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def end(message):
    if message.text == "Искать фильмы" :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="ДЛЯ ПРОСМОТРА ФИЛЬМА ВВЕДИТЕ КОД В ФОРМАТЕ<<123>>")


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам, проблема была в хэндлерах с одинаковыми типами данных, решилось через объединение содержимого двух хэндлеров в одном через цикл if:

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_message(message):
    if message.text == "ИСКАТЬ ФИЛЬМЫ":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ДЛЯ ПРОСМОТРА ФИЛЬМА ВВЕДИТЕ КОД В ФОРМАТЕ<<123>>')
    else:
        val1 = db_table_val(message.text)
        pic1 = db_table_pic(message.text)
        rkb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        rkb.add('ИСКАТЬ ФИЛЬМЫ')
        if pic1 == None:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Фильм № ' + message.text + ' называется:             ' + val1, reply_markup=rkb)
        else:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=pic1, caption='Фильм № '+message.text+' называется:             '+val1, reply_markup=rkb)
```